# Trying to generate an collection of objects from an base model

Tags: python

I'm trying to make an small orm for tinydb but stuck in an problem with classes and collections of instances:

With the folling code:

```
class SubModelChild(object):

    def __init__(self):
        print "IN INIT OF SubModelChild"

    def cmd2(self):
        print "IN cmd2 of SubModelChild"

    def search(self):
        print "IN search of SubModelChild"
        result = []
        for x in range(0, 3):
            rec = {'id': x, 'text': 'text %d' % x}
            result.append(rec)
        return result

class SubModelMaster(object):
    _child = None

    def __init__(self):
        print "IN INIT OF SubModelMaster"
        self._child = SubModelChild()

    def cmd1(self):
        print "IN cmd1 of SubModelMaster"


class BaseModel(object):
    _store = None
    _em = None

    def __init__(self):
        print "IN INIT OF BaseModel"
        self._store =  SubModelMaster()
        self._em = self._store._child

    @classmethod
    def objects(cls):
        return Manager(cls)

    def cmd3(self):
        print "IN cmd3 of BaseModel"


class Manager(object):
    def __init__(self, model_class):
        self.model_class = model_class
        self._em = model_class._em

    def _model(self, result):
        if result is None: return None
        instance = self.model_class(**result)
        return instance

    def find(self):
        print "IN find of Manager"
        return list(map(self._model, self._em.search()))

class Address(BaseModel):
    address = None
    city = None

# Works
adr = Address()
adr._store.cmd1()
adr._em.cmd2()
adr.cmd3()
for rec in adr._em.search():
    print rec

# Don't works
collection = Address.objects().find()
for rec in collection.find():
    print rec
```

This works:

```
adr = Address()
adr._store.cmd1()
adr._em.cmd2()
adr.cmd3()
for rec in adr._em.search():
    print rec
```

and this don't:

```
collection = Address.objects().find()
for rec in collection.find():
    print rec
```

Whit this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./testeobj.py", line 74, in <module>
    collection = Address.objects().find()
  File "./testeobj.py", line 59, in find
    return list(map(self._model, self._em.search()))
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'search'
```

Someone can help me to find an solution ?

Comment: what do you expect it to do?

Comment: `Manager` gets initialized with a model **class**, so `self._em = model_class._em` is getting the **class** variable `Address._em` which is `None`.  Should it instead take an instance of `BaseModel`?